# Android: Colocar FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

Tengo un problema al colocar dos FloatingActionButton, quiero colocar el boton de Home al lado del de Imagenes pero no me esta quedando, espero y me puedan ayudar.Gracias

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:title="Bienvenido">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/data_checkin" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/picture"
            android:tint="#FFF"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fabmain2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fabmain2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/home"
            android:tint="#FFF"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeScot"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto amigo :

```
   <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/picture"
            android:tint="#FFF"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab_home"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/home"
            android:tint="#FFF"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Si Keops ya quedo!!!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias Keops :3

Answer (score 1):

Ten presente que si quieres los dos botones alineados, estos deben tener los mismos margenes.

Para alinear los botones, en el de lado izquierdo define gravedad:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|left|end"
```

sería:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left|end"
    android:src="@drawable/picture"
    android:tint="#FFF"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/home"
    android:tint="#FFF"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: Hola Elenasys, ya se colocan horizontalmente pero estan quedando de extremo a extremo y me gustaria que no estubieran tan separados, estaria bien la separacion a un centimetro. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.